# Армянин или армян?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, согласование, числительные

Пишу статью. С коллегой возник спор о правильности написания предложения.
Я пишу: "В 1893 году в городе насчитывалось 7243 **жителей**, в том числе 3807 грузин (52,6 %) и 2894 **армян** (40,0 %)".
Мой коллега пишет: "В 1893 году в городе насчитывалось 7243 **жителя**, в том числе 3807 грузин (52,6 %) и 2894 **армянина** (40,0 %)".
Кто из нас двоих прав?

Comment: Тот, кто способен обосновать, видимо. Вы-то как аргументируете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

Числительные по правилам русского языка согласуются с существительными таким образом:

**Один** (одна, одно) — именительный падеж (**армянин**, житель, грузин);
**два** (две), **три, четыре** — родительный (**армянина**, жителя, грузина);
**пять - двадцать** — родительный падеж множественного числа (**армян**, жителей, грузин).

*В числительных, которые **больше двадцати**, согласованию подлежит только **число единиц*** (число десятков, сотен, тысяч и т. д. не имеет значения):
724**3** жителя, 380**7** грузин, 289**4** армянина.
[**числительные**](http://nekin.info/math/imya_chislitelnoye.htm)

Так что Ваш коллега абсолютно прав.

P.S. Есть даже "запоминалочка" для существительных (национальностей) в родительном падеже множественного числа:
Уважают человека у туркмен, татар, узбеков,
У таджиков и армян, у монголов и цыган,
У якутов и тунгусов, у башкир и белорусов,
У киргизов и грузин, у бурят и осетин.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое. Очень признателен

Answer (score 1):

2894 армянина, так же как и 4 армянина. Если числительное заканчивается на 4 (а также на 2 и 3), то существительные ставятся в родительном падеже единственного числа. (А в именительном падеже — армянин.)

Comment: @shampar Но я дополнил ответ, спасибо!

Comment: Я увидел. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо. Просветили неуча:)

Answer (score 1):

Коллега прав - формально так и выходит, но обычно в таких текстах "сглаживают углы" (иначе можно озадачиться числом "армянок" и т. п.), например:

*всего жителеей - 7243 человека, из них 3807 (человек) - грузины, 2894 (человека) - армяне.*

Другой вариант: *среди них грузин - 3807 человек, армян - 2894 человека.*

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам